# How can I change the time limit for webClient.UploadData()?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, webclient

I am using `WebClient.UploadData()` to do a post on a Java server. How can I extend the time limit? (It times out every time I am trying to do some debugging)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The WebClient doesn't have a timeout property, however it is possible to inherit from the WebClient to give access to Timeout on the internal WebRequest used:

```
 public class WebClientEx : WebClient
 {
     public int Timeout {get; set;}

     protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
     {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.Timeout = Timeout;
        return request;
     }
 }
```

Usage:

```
 var myClient = new WebClientEx();
 myClient.Timeout = 900000 // Daft timeout period
 myClient.UploadData(myUri, myData);
```

Comment: Great answer. FYI I used this and it also works with `WebClient.UploadValues()`

Comment: Great , this is so helpful!

Answer (score 5):

So for those who code in VB...

```
Public Class WebClientExtended
    Inherits WebClient
    Public Property Timeout() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Timeout
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Timeout = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Timeout As Integer

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(address As Uri) As WebRequest
        Dim request = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        request.Timeout = Timeout
        Return request
    End Function
End Class

Function UploadFile(ByVal URL As String, ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String)

    'Call API to Upload File
    Dim myWebClient As New WebClientExtended
    myWebClient.Timeout = 10 * 60 * 1000
    Dim responseArray As Byte()
    Dim responseString As String = ""

    Try
        responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(URL, FilePath + "/" + FileName)
        responseString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
    Catch ex As Exception
        responseString = "Error: " + ex.Message
    End Try

    Return responseString

End Function
```