# UploadFile / Webclient - Timeout configuration

Tags: c#, timeout, webclient

I'm have:

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
           {          
               client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
                DirectoryInfo diretorio2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
               FileInfo[] Arquivos2 = diretorio2.GetFiles("*.*");
               foreach (FileInfo fileinfo2 in Arquivos2)
               {
               client.UploadFile("ftp://" + ftp + "/" + dir + fileinfo2.Name, @"C:\" + fileinfo2.Name);
               }
```

I'm having some problems with this code, maybe firewall ... I needed to put a timeout to display a messagebox with the cause of the problem, how can I configure the timeout in that case?

Comment: Question is unclear - you don't have any place where you catch an exception, so what is it you wish to display in a message box?

Comment: I dunno, I'm kinda lost, just need to put a timeout on that uploadfile.. On some computers, the upload never completes, needed to know what the cause, but does not display error

Comment: this is how you set a timeout
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237966/how-can-i-change-the-time-limit-for-webclient-uploaddata]

if i recall correctly though the default timeout for webclient is 100 seconds or so.

Comment: Are these big files? Sometimes uploads just take a long time, you have to be patient.

Comment: No, small files, 20, 25kb...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237966/how-can-i-change-the-time-limit-for-webclient-uploaddata

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the time limit for webClient.UploadData()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237966/how-can-i-change-the-time-limit-for-webclient-uploaddata)